# Vue.JS POST request pass null bearer token and failed with status code 401

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, axios

I'm backend guy who wants to gain some Vue.js skills. In my app I've got Ruby on Rails as backend and Vue.js as front-end with a standard JWT token flow. I'm trying to send a POST request (`fetchAllProductsRequest`) to the backend that will trigger some background job using below code:

`index.js`

```
const fetchAllProductsRequest = (self) => {
  const jwtToken = self.$store.state.idToken;

  return axios
    .post(`/api/v1/imports/products/fetch_all`,{
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.data)
};
```

Quite surprisingly I get an error: `Request failed with status code 401`. When I debugging it on the backend side I see that I send an empty token inside the header:

```
[1] pry(#<Api::V1::Imports::ProductsController>)> params[:headers]
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"Authorization"=>"Bearer null", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Accept"=>"application/json"} permitted: false>
```

Here is a function that triggers `fetchAllProductsRequest` which is responsible for POST request:

`fetch_all.vue`

```
<script>
import {
  fetchAllProductsRequest,
} from '../../api/imports'

import ModalController from '../general/modal_controller'

export default {
  name: 'BackboneFetchAll',
  data() {
    return { }
  },
  components: {
    MoonLoader
  },
  computed: {
    databaseSyncInProgress() {
      return this.$store.getters.getDatabaseSyncStatus;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async syncAll() {
      let confirmationText = `Do you want to sync all Backbone products?`

      if (await ModalController.showConfirmation('Confirmation', confirmationText)) {
        try {
          ModalController.showLoader()
          await fetchAllProductsRequest(this)
          this.$store.commit('setSyncingProductsInProgress', value)
          const successMessage = `Database synchronization has been queued`
          await ModalController.showToast('', successMessage)
        } catch (data) {
          const errorMessage = `Error occurred during queueing products to sync - `
          ModalController.showToast('', errorMessage + data?.message, 'error')
        } finally {
          ModalController.hideLoader()
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

What did I missed?

Comment: Are you sure `self.$store.state.idToken` is populated when you're making the request?

Comment: @tao inside console.log(self.$store.state.idToken) I've got `null`. How to fill it with a token?

Comment: Call `fetchAllProductsRequest` after the token is populated. There are many ways to do it. One would be to authenticate in router, before accessing any route of your app, except `/login`. Another is to place a watcher on your store token property and fetch products after authentication. The real problem here is the code you shared is irrelevant to the question being asked. In the sense that the code you've shown doesn't need to change. It's correct. You just need to delay running it after you get the token. And you're not showing where you call it from.

Comment: In the above I'm guessing you have an authentication mechanism integrated with both FE and BE and it works as expected (e.g: a token is generated and the BE accepts it, when FE uses it). If you don't, and you're asking how to implement authentication, that's too broad a question. You should do some research, try something and, should you run into any specific problems, ask about those separately.